# How to split the string which is in japanese characters?

Tags: regex, hive, python-2.x

I have a japanese string "さいたま市　中央区" in my hive table. I just want the first part of the string from table i.e さいたま市.

I have tried with split function and regular expression, its not working. I tried with hive and python

Tried all these below, it didnt work

```
select split("さいたま市　中央区",'')[0];
select regexp_extract("さいたま市　中央区","^(.*?)\\s(.*)",1)
select regexp_extract("さいたま市　中央区","[ur'[\u4e00-\ufaff]']",1)
```

Just I want the first part of string.

Comment: What does Python have to do with your question?

Comment: You're still looking to split on a space too so Japanese also has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: I tried doing `.split()` on your string above, worked like you expected. `"さいたま市　中央区".split()`

Comment: `repr("""I have a japanese string "さいたま市　中央区" in my hive table""")` gives me `'\'I have a japanese string "さいたま市\\u3000中央区" in my hive table\''`, can you corroborate that this is in fact what you are trying to process? Does the obvious `thing.split('\u3000')` not do what you want? And again, please [edit] to clarify how this is related to Python and whether -- as indicated in a comment -- you are actually using Python 2 rather than the recommended version Python 3.

Comment: Note also that if you are in fact in Python 2, we need to know the exact encoding of the file you are trying to process. If you don't know, maybe show a hex dump of a few bytes where the actual space-like character is visible (but just a few bytes of surrounding context, not the whole file). Maybe see also hints in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: @tripleee Thank you sooooo much.. it worked . This is what I wanted  thing.split('\u3000'). 
Using python I was trying to read the contents of text file and then split one by one. Either from hive table or from text file, i wanted the firts part of string. Thanks a ton ...it worked !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this as an answer as well ...

Copy/pasting the text from your question and running `repr` gives me

```py
>>> repr("""I have a japanese string "さいたま市　中央区" in my hive table""")
'\'I have a japanese string "さいたま市\\u3000中央区" in my hive table\''
```

This suggests that `split(... that text ..., '\u3000')[0]` should produce the result you want.

The expression `"[ur'[\u4e00-\ufaff]']"` looks extremely wrong; correcting it to `ur'[\u4e00-\ufaff]'` would perhaps work as well. Or maybe try simply `"[\u4e00-\ufaff]"`.

Comment: Not sure whether the (Hive?) syntax you are using permits general Python expressions or just some subset. Again, whether you are using Python 2 or Python 3 might also matter. In order to make this useful for future visitors, I urge you again to edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: Thank you again for your time. 
I am stuck up with this issue- Now I am able to get the part of the string. Next is to search this sub string in hive table 
Eg : select * from <table_name> where <col_name> = 'さいたま市'

Since its japanese character, how to do search in table.

Comment: Sounds like you should post a new question. If you are asking about Hive, I have no idea.

Comment: Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58535736/how-to-search-the-japanese-string-in-hive-table is what happened next.

Answer (score 0):

So one thing to keep in mind, Japanese spaces are not the same as English spaces (Im not sure why but the ascii values are different). This means that you cant use \s or try to use `split` using normal spaces. (Like you have attempted in your example)

The regex you would need is- `(.+)\h(.+)` where you look for horizontal whitespace instead of regular spaces. [implementation here](https://regex101.com/r/ChUobQ/1)

Comment: This is not working for me. I tried,  select regexp_extract(<col_name>,"(.+)\h(.+)") from <table_name>

Comment: hmm thats odd as it works fine on regex101 (which I have linked), maybe there is something else going on ?

Comment: it just returns blank as output :(

Comment: @MJM I dont think you escaped the backslash since your feeding it in as a string

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. You just need to copy/paste that non-standard Japanese space character into an argument of `split()` function when using python 2.

```
>>> a = "さいたま市　中央区"
>>> a.split('　')      # use this for python 2.*
['さいたま市', '中央区']
>>> a.split()          # this works fine in python 3
['さいたま市', '中央区']
>>>
```

Comment: the thing is all these strings are in txt file. Below code I have tried in python 2:

test_list = []
with open("T.txt") as f:
 for item in f:
   item=item.split(' ')
   test_list.append(item[0])
  print test_list

Comment: @MJM you need to change to python3 or make sure you have copy/pasted `a.split('　')` from my answer that contains the Japanese space character.