# How to search the japanese string in hive table?

Tags: regex, hive

I have a table japan_dt with below schema:

```
Prefecture       city
北海道            札幌市
```

Now I want to run the select query on the above table something like:

```
select prefecture from japan_dt  where city = '札幌市'
```

output should be

```
北海道
```

How to achieve this in HIVE ?

I have tried with

```
select prefecture from japan_dt  where city rlike '札幌市'
```

it's not working

Comment: Are you sure that this question is related to regexes? I f not, you should remove the tag.

Comment: `its not working` - what makes you think it's not working?

Comment: @Wiktor : I am searching it in hive table, the above regular expression will work in java. 

I just want to know, how to give the search value for japanese string in select query

Comment: `rlike` will only return the *whole* record, not part of it.